# Retrieve game details that their level's value is higher than 1/10 the sum of guilds levels

Tags: mysql

I've a database which contains tables:

- *Quest*:

  ```
  PK  Name
  PK  qName
      goal
  ```
- *Guild*:

  ```
  PK  Name
  PK  gName
      level
  ```
- *Game*:

  ```
  PK  Name
      MaxPlayer
      levels
      uName
  ```
- *GuildQuest*:

  ```
  PK  Name
  PK  gName
  PK  qName
  ```

I need to **retrieve  the game details that their level's value is higher than 1/10 the sum of guilds levels**

This is what I've build so far:

```
SELECT
  Name, MaxPlayer, levels, uName
  SUM(level) AS guildsLevels
FROM
  Guild
GROUP BY
  level
```

I need to add the multiplication by 0.10 of the sum which I don't know how to do, and then check every game that its value is bigger than sum of guild levels multiplied by 10%.

I'm using MySQL (and PhpMyAdmin to run the queries).

Comment: Would you please provide the sample data and expected output? This will help us. The query provided in question will not work as GROUP BY clause is not defined as per SELECT clause.

Comment: For the actual question, it would be best to provide sample data as well. It's not clear what you are after. ("sum of levels" for example, does that refer to sum of levels per game, per guild, per player, the total sum, etc.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the `Guild.gName = Game.Name`, I think you are looking for something like this:

```
select
    ga.Name
  , ga.MaxPlayer
  , ga.levels
  , ga.uName
  , gu.GuildsLevels
from Game ga 
  inner join (
    select gName, GuildsLevels=sum(level)
      from Guilds
      group by gName
      ) as gu on ga.Name   = gu.gName 
             and ga.levels>=(gu.guildslevels*0.10)
```